# Adding na.rm to a function with multiple arguments

Tags: r, na

```
mydata<-structure(list(x1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 9.2, 
    0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x1", 
    "x2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -78L))
```

There are 2 columns in my data. First one has 78 rows, second one has 31 rows. So When I import them directly from txt, rows after 31st row are getting NA. 
And I am trying to find each columns' autocovariance lag1 with `acvf` function from `library(itsmr)`. And to obtain `lag1`, I am adding `1` as an argument.

```
acvf(mydata$x1, 1)
acvf(mydata$x2, 1)
```

When I try to add `na.rm` to function I am getting this error;

> acvf(mydata$x2, 1, na.rm = T) Error in acvf(mydata$x2, 1, na.rm = T) :
>   unused argument (na.rm = T)

So how can I ignore NAs in a column with `na.rm` or with another solution?

Comment: Maybe `na.omit` or `na.exclude`?

Comment: With these function, all rows after 31st row are being removed for both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `na.rm` argument in that function. You could apply the function over the data frame with a `sapply` and a `na.omit` wrapped around the columns.

```
t(sapply(mydata, function(x) acvf(na.omit(x), 1)))
#           [,1]        [,2]
# x1 0.005023011 0.001431919
# x2 2.638501561 0.283323151
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are calling doesn't have such an argument as `na.rm`, nor any equivalent.

To achieve what you want, you will need to modify the supplied data to the function.

You can use subsetting and the `is.na` function to keep only the values that are not NA.
i.e.

```
acvf(mydata$x2[!is.na(mydata$x2)], 1)
```